# FactoryGirl set updated_at attribute in factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, factory-bot

Using FactoryGirl 4.7.0, I have a factory that I want to specify the updated_at attribute to a date in the past.

```
factory :living_arrangement do

    trait :expired do
        updated_at Date.new(2012, 3, 6)
        # or
        updated_at { Date.new(2012, 3, 6) }
    end
end
```

However these are not working. The factory updated_at attribute keeps getting set back to `Date.now`.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I know this was a long time ago! Did any of these answers end up helping? I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: I've selected the answer I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to use a callback for when the factory gets created, like so

```
factory :living_arrangement do
    trait :expired do
        after :create do |living|
            living.updated_at = Date.new(2012, 3, 6)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think this won't save the new value of `updated_at`.

Comment: Yeah, seems like you probably would prefer something like `living.touch` to reset updated_at. But I found that dixpac's answer did work quite well for me

Comment: Though using [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) (As dixpac mentions) does seems to be an easier and cleaner way to

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, but you need to save and skip validations/callbacks, and that should be done `after :create`, like so:

```rb
trait :expired do
  after :create do |living_arrangement|
    living_arrangement.update_columns(updated_at: 2.months.ago)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord’s automatic timestamping feature sets `Time.now` for `created_at and updated_at` fields overriding `FactoryGiril` values. That’s ActiveRecord’s default behavior. Fortunately it can be disabled with

`LivingArrangement.record_timestamps = false`

Chances are that after creating a model with a custom timestamp you’ll want to turn automatic timestamping back on. But turning it off and on in many places in your unit tests would be pretty cumbersome. You could create test_helper, something like this

```
 def without_timestamping_of(*klasses)
    if block_given?
      klasses.delete_if { |klass| !klass.record_timestamps }
      klasses.each { |klass| klass.record_timestamps = false }
      begin
        yield
      ensure
        klasses.each { |klass| klass.record_timestamps = true }
      end
    end
  end
```

The you could use this helper in you specs like this

```
without_timestamping_of LivingArrangement do
  create(:living_arrangement, :created_at => 1.week.ago, :updated_at => 1.week.ago)
end
```

or multiple factories

```
without_timestamping_of LivingArrangement, User do
  create(:living_arrangement, :created_at => 1.week.ago, :updated_at => 1.week.ago)
  create(:user, :created_at => 1.week.ago, :updated_at => 1.week.ago)
end
```

Another common approach would be to use [TimeCop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem